# Validating preferences in inappsettingskit

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, inappsettingskit

I want to use the kIASKAppSettingChanged notification in inappsettingskit to validate preferences when they are changed.

I know the notification contains the new value of the preference that was changed but does it contain the old value anywhere?

Or is there a smart way I can get hold of this (other than cacheing all my preferences in memory)?

I need to be able to roll back the preference value if the validation check fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, InAppSettingsKit does not provide the old value. It shouldn't be that hard to extend it though. Just search for `kIASKAppSettingChanged` and modify all calls to include both the old and the new value in the `-postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` calls.